# React Native GeoLocation Offline Mode

Tags: reactjs, geolocation, react-native, react-native-ios

Does React Native geo-location work in offline mode? I am testing on my device and geolocation.watchPosition works great, but when I flip to airplane mode I get a location error. I opened my Google Maps app and can see location is still tracking (in airplane mode) there. How can I get geo-location in react native to work in offline mode? If not possible, what are some alternatives?

Note: I am testing on IOS but looking for a solution that will work on both Android and IOS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i have tried it 
i works but not always
it depends on your signal too even if you do not connect to internet
it depends on your device too to receive signal
in my case, i am using asus zenfone 6 for a test when i am connected to internet it works well with a good accuracy but when i am not connected to the internet sometimes it work but really bad accuracy
in other case, i am using samsung s7 for a test when i am connected to the internet it works really well with a very good accuracy but when i am not connected to the internet sometimes it work(work most/more than asus zenfone 6) but with not good accuracy

hope that answer your question if anyone have a suggestion on how i fix the bad accuracy without internet please leave a comment

Answer (score -1):

> 1. Yes you can use in offline mode By using this code it works in offline mode 
>      very correctly
>
>    - Don't forget to give location permission in manifest file
>    - `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`

```
      class GeoLoc extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        latitude: null,
        longitude: null,
        error: null,
      };
}

componentDidMount(){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( (position)=>{
        //const ipos = JSON.stringify(Position);
        this.setState({
            latitude: position.coords.latitude,
            longitude: position.coords.longitude,
            error: null,
          });
    },
    (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
    { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 }
  );
}

render(){
    return(
        <View>
        <Text>Latitude: {this.state.latitude}</Text>
        <Text>Longitude: {this.state.longitude}</Text>
        <Text> {this.state.error} </Text>
       </View> 
    )
}
```

}

Comment: This code looks just like my online location retrieval code and it does not work for me offline.